# What do the numbers under the thumb icon mean in Dungeon Defenders?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

When I look at gear on the ground, there are two numbers just under the thumb icon - a fraction like 171\220. What do these numbers mean?

[image: Dungeon Defenders numbers]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That number your inventory (Item box) space occupied. It tells you how much space free you have left in your inventory. As you pick up more items the number on the left will go up :)

Comment: It's in addition to the upgrade numbers. At the top, closer to the thumb. And the first number starts out pretty high, not at 1.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: done, sorry for the confusion